# System.BadImageFormatException: Image is too small .Net Core MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have recently deployed my application to the server and below is the error I get. When I run it locally, everything works fine.

The application is uisng Microsoft.AspNetCore 1.1.3

I also tried to force the application to use x86.

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Image is too small.
   at System.Reflection.Throw.ImageTooSmall()
   at     System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEHeaders.SkipDosHeader(PEBinaryReader& reader, Boolean& isCOFFOnly)
   at System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEHeaders..ctor(Stream peStream, Int32 size, Boolean isLoadedImage)
   at System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEReader..ctor(Stream peStream, PEStreamOptions options, Int32 size)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ModuleMetadata.CreateFromStream(Stream peStream, PEStreamOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.CreateMetadataReference(String path)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, MetadataReferenceFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorReferenceManager.GetCompilationReferences()
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorReferenceManager.get_CompilationReferences()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRoslynCompilationService.CreateCompilation(String compilationContent, String assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRoslynCompilationService.Compile(RelativeFileInfo fileInfo, String compilationContent)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorCompilationService.Compile(RelativeFileInfo file)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.CompilerCache.CreateCacheEntry(String relativePath, String normalizedPath, Func`2 compile)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.CompilerCache.GetOrAdd(String relativePath, Func`2 compile)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(String relativePath)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet`1 expirationTokens, String relativePath, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, String pageName, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, String viewName, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, String viewName, Boolean isMainPage)
```

[image: Platform details]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the dll files weren't copied over correctly. The file sizes to the publish and the deployment were the same but when I copied everything over from scratch, the website started working.